# How to use decodeString in jsoncpp to decode a string containing unicode characters

Tags: c++, string, unicode, jsoncpp

I have read all the jsoncpp documentation [here](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/class_json_1_1_reader.html#f1da6c976ad1e96c742804c3853eef94) and I know how to use jsoncpp for char * and std::string but, I need a way to obtain `wchar` data from my json file. I am guessing this can be done using the `decodeString` function present in json_reader.cpp. The documentation doesn't describe whether the Token is an in paramter or an out parameter or how exactly am i supposed to obtain that Token, considering it's an [in] parameter. I have searched for over 2 days now and I can't seem to find a lead.

Any sort of suggestions or links are highly welcome.

Comment: What is the point in `wchar`? If it is some api requirement, then that api should have some sort of [convert_from_utf8](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#fromUtf8) [function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I need to read german text from a json file and convert it to a .dat file. But the text gets written as: wÃ¼tend when it should actually be wütend. Hence, I need the wchar.

Comment: `ü` in utf8 is a byte sequence `C3 BC`. So it is `Ã¼` when encoded as ascii. How are you reading that .dat file? I guess your viewer uses ascii encoding, which is not a good idea when dealing with unicode.

Comment: Are you converting for Windows, Java, or what?

Comment: I am converting it for windows and am using Microsoft Visual Studio for compilation purposes. I figured out how to view the "ü" via notepad. I had to change my project's character set from Unicode to Multibyte. However I am still facing some issues. For values such as \u0100 or \u0643 etc (\uwxyz with x being greater than 0) the decoding doesn't work quite well. Any idea as to why this could be happening?

Comment: No. All new Windows project should be UNICODE. Multi-Byte is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

Windows uses UTF16 UNICODE standard. New Windows projects should be setup with UNICODE settings.

Linux and internet net based systems use UTF8 standard.

You receive data through json, it is probably in UTF8, available as `std::string` or `const wchar`. Convert that to UTF16. Using:

```
std::string get_utf8(const std::wstring &wstr)
{
    if (wstr.empty()) return std::string();
    int sz = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, &wstr[0], (int)wstr.size(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
    std::string res(sz, 0);
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, &wstr[0], (int)wstr.size(), &res[0], sz, 0, 0);
    return res;
}

std::wstring get_utf16(const std::string &str)
{
    if (str.empty()) return std::wstring();
    int sz = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), 0, 0);
    std::wstring res(sz, 0);
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), &res[0], sz);
    return res;
}
```

For example,

```
std::string fromJSON = getjson(...);
std::wstring ws = get_utf16(fromJSON);
```

Now Windows can display `ws`

```
MessageBox(0, ws.c_str(), 0, 0);
```

Convert it back to UTF8 before sending it to JSON:

```
std::string str = get_utf8(ws);
set_JSON_string(str);
```

Comment: Barmak, thank you so much for your explanation but, I am sort of stuck with using MultiByteToWideChar on Windows XP. The above code works just fine on Vista and above but, on XP i just get blocks instead of the actual data.

Comment: The XP error could be from JSON, or maybe it is from `MultiByteToWideChar` but I can't guess what is happening.

Comment: I figured out why it wasn't working on XP. It was because I hadn't configured the "Language setting for non-Unicode programs" setting in the control panel. Everything worked perfectly fine after that.